# Block outgoing text

Tags: android

How to design the BroadcastReceiver class that will block outgoing SMS.

abortBroadcast();  does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
if ((actionType.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)))
{
    setResultData(null); // I tried this and abortBroadcast(); as well
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use edit and append your previous question instead of adding a new one? This question here has no information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov. The post you are referring to is for Call. I am able to manage calls but want to know how to manage SMS. any help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not though you can intercept outgoing sms using content observer